# Cannot retrieve resultset data

Tags: mysql

I created a folder in "MySQL Server 5.7\Data" And copied frm,myd,myi files there from another database folder ( mysql 5.1 )
However the data is encrpted and there is a program that sends queries, decrypts and displays the result. ( written in Delphi 7, db component Zeoslib )
Whenever i try to search a big table, i get "Cannot retrieve resultset data" error. I am a total noob and dont know how to solve this.Any suggestions ?

edit: I am not particularly concerned about efficiency and i didnt write the decryptor program, i just downloaded it along with mysql 5.1 data files.Because the data is encrypted i am stuck with using this program for queries.I know several people managed to get this to work so it should be possible.I want to change mysql settings such that the program wont complain when searching big tables ( 50 million entries )

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. We need more to work here. Where are you searching a big table, in the app or in a MySQL client? Did it work before you upgraded MySQL? What is the table definition of the "big table" and what do you call "big". Please add as much information in the question to avoid many comments asking for clarification. I'm voting to close for now until you edited your question to make it clear.

Comment: "such that the program wont complain" what is it complaining about? Do you have actual error messages

Comment: this is the error "Cannot retrieve resultset data"

Answer (score 3):

The main issue you are seeing is based on the nature of the encryption.  The Delphi application appears to not be using any native MySQL encryption/decryption mechanisms for the data.  This will result in certain disadvantages when querying for data.  Although the decrypted data is visible to the application while in use, native to MySQL, it has no what of indexing any encrypted data fields in any optimized way as the values would be unknown.  This would result in long query times as most likely all queries would be scanning the whole table to deliver any results.

If you can, use the Delphi application, or similarly developed application to export the data unencrypted into a file, easily parsed by MySQL (csv, SQL statements, etc.) that can be imported into your MySQL 5.7 database instance.

This will allow you to create indexes on the unencrypted data to run your queries as necessary.

If you need to reencrypt the data, you can use the native functions of MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html

However, you will still be unable to index those columns in any workable way to query on those columns.  I would recommend if possible that any queries be done on any columns that can remain unencrypted and therefore be indexed accordingly to optimize the execution plans.

Comment: +1 for this and I second it. Go back to the status quo ante - the motto of the programmer should be the same as the doctor - [first do no harm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocratic_Oath#.22First_do_no_harm.22). Then get the unencrypted data in the form of SQL statements - mysqldump probably won't do you any  good. You might have to mess around with editors and find/replace with a bit of sed, awk and grep thrown in. Good luck and welcome to the forum :-)